# SwiftUI | How to hide cancel button in alert window?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

While testing new `alert` method in iOS 15([document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:message:)-8584l)), I just found a weird behavior that alert has.

#### Description

This is the codes:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                show = true
            }) {
                Text("Alert")
            }
        }
        .alert("alert", isPresented: $show) {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("button1")
            }
            Button("button2", role: .destructive, action: {})
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added only 2 buttons but SwiftUI just adds `Cancel` button at the end of the buttons.

[image]

However, it doesn't happen when any of the buttons doesn't have a role.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                show = true
            }) {
                Text("Alert")
            }
        }
        .alert("alert", isPresented: $show) {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("button1")
            }
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("button1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

It's really weird. I even have no idea that it's intended by Apple or just a bug.

#### Question

Therefore my question is, how can I remove that cancel button after I added a button with a role. Is there any way to do this or I have to just accept it..

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: It makes _sense_ to have a cancel button if there is a destructive action, for the user to back-out. I'm curious what your buttons may be labelled / used for because this may be more of a design decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As role destructive button is for deletes user data, or performs an irreversible operation according to Apple docs.

In the alert view maybe because of you have a button with role `.destructive` so the alert default add a .cancel button. For closing the alert you should define a button with role `.cancel`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                show = true
            }) {
                Text("Alert")
            }
        }
        .alert("alert", isPresented: $show) {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("button1")
            }
            Button("button2", role: .cancel, action: {})
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The result]